# Where() returns duplicate rows

Tags: c#, .net, linq, where-clause

I have a simple table/Model:

```
public class Note
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string note { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
    public Guid InvestorId { get; set; }
}
```

I can query it with

```
db.Database.SqlQuery<Note>("SELECT * FROM Notes WHERE InvestorId = '" + id + "'").ToList()
```

and it returns all the notes for the id, as expected.  I try to do it with LINQ with:

```
db.Notes.Where(x => x.InvestorId == id).ToList()
```

and I get the same number of rows back but all the notes are duplicates of the first one.  What is the correct way to do this in LINQ without returning duplicates?

Comment: Can you see by profiler(or such tool) which query runs on server?

Comment: When you say "all the notes are duplicates" are all four fields the same, or Id/CreateDate different while the note field is the same?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.  I have been playing around with the table trying different techniques and I had populated the Id (not InvestorId) in Notes with the same number.  Apparently the Sql query doesn't care about this but LINQ doesn't like it.

Comment: okay, so can you gave your query to us? it seems that my answer its gave you a some idea :D

Comment: That's very interesting, since LINQ utimately goes to SQL (and probably SQL nearly identical to yours).  I'm assuming you are using LINQ-to-Entities, and I'm gonna guess that it's somewhere between the data being returned from the db, and it be mapped to the Note objects that it goes astray.

Comment: I used the same query I had originally.  I am pretty new to EF and LINQ.  Not sure on your question about LINQ-to-Entities.

Comment: @BlooSki: you would be expected to.  If I'm right, the problem is buried deep in EF.  EF does some funky things, and MS is still working the bugs out.  LINQ-To-Sql is much more stable-- it's a shame MS is developing it further.